# Number type in JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I just started to learn JSON :

which one of the following is correct :

```
var json = {"age":22} // my book writes like this
```

or

```
var json = {age:22} // internet show example like this
```

PHP storm generates

```
argument type number is not assignable  to parameter type string
```

for both of them.

If the second one is correct show what is the difference with JS object then.

Comment: Both are correct, quotes are redundant in this case.

Comment: btw why PHPstorm generates the warning, am I crazy??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you're using the term JSON, but the example you show isn't JSON. If you're talking about plain JavaScript objects, then both examples you gave are correct. When people refer to JSON, they're usually referring to the data type sent over client/server exchanges, which is very specific, and there are linters for that (see [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/), for example). PHPStorm's error is incorrect.

[image: output]

Comment: thanks. so the first one could be considered as normal JS object right? that's why both of them still could print the value.

Comment: @hansf., both of the examples you gave are perfectly valid JS objects. But only the first example is the JSON data type (without the `var whatever =` part).

Comment: Thank you , i just want to follow the valid standar, but I trust you now!

Comment: @hansf., no problem my friend, glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Basically JSON are key value pairs , its basically object for storing data

- var json = {"age":"22"} : if you use like this you can get value like json["age"] and json.age , both are helpful in certain situations and value returned is string , you need to convert it (only its required)
- var json = {age :22 }  : if you use like this you cant get value like json[""] format , only json.age can be used to get
- var json = {"age":22} should be fine as your using type as number and moreover you can fetch it using json["age"]

The above scenarios mentioned are respect to your functionalites and usage of them

Comment: so you say both of them are valid JSON??

Comment: @hansf.according to JSON validators , var json={"key":22} is correct , and if your json has to many data and looping is required and modify the data according to it this fine , like 
for(var key in jsonObj){
     console.log( jsonObj[key]); // consoles values in your json

}

Answer (score 1):

Both ways are valid in Javascript. But the quotes are needed in specific cases, like :

```
var obj = {
    'foo bar': 0, 
    'foo-bar': 0, 
    '': 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When working with JSON a validator/linter is an essential tool, especially dealing with larger sets of data.

Sending both of these through http://jsonlint.com/ the results are:

The first verifies as Valid JSON, the second reveals:

```
    Parse error on line 1:
        {age: 22}
    -----^
    Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```